# Rails. How generate url by routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have routes by `rake routes`. It's near 800 strings. Now I want check validate route (errors, 404, ActionNotFound etc). Ideal if I can check access to pages for authorize and non-authorize users.

If I check by hand - it's very long (from route to url, then open page, then ...). May be have instruments for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to expand your controller tests, write some integration tests, and most of all add [routing tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) using `assert_routing`.

Automated testing suites are the way to do this.

Comment: There's an infinite number of ways to do this, but the most sensible one is to use the Rails route testing facility and some comprehensive controller tests.

Comment: hm... I'm want find alternative solution, because have problems with tests :(

Comment: What do you mean "have problems with tests"? You're trying to test things. Automation is the way to go about this.

Comment: I'm never wrote tests. I'm beginner in study rails, but now not have time for learning test theme. Therefore instrument.

Comment: You **always** have time to learn about unit testing. You can either spend the relatively small amount of time now to figure it out, or you can spend hundreds of hours testing and re-testing your application by hand. Rails makes testing unusually easy, as it includes a full testing subsystem.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But now, just looking for a tool.

Comment: what do you think a test _is_?